# Using Python decorators to enable/disable certain parts of a program

Tags: python, decorator

I have a bunch of scripts that are essentially data preparation steps, to set up data for simulation models. I very often want to run only parts of it, say either 'phase1' or 'phase2', but most 'phases' are more than one line, so commenting out isn't very convenient. So I generally do:

```
# Phase 1
if True:
  do_step_1('high')
  do_step_2()
  for i in range(1,10):
    do_step_3()

#Phase 2
if True:
  do_step_1('low')
  do_something_else()
```

And then change True to False as needed.

Now, this is quite cumbersome. Sometimes, phases depend on each other (so when I run 3 I also need to run 1), they are nested, etc.

What I want to do, is have some way to pass an argument to my script that would run one or more 'phases', and I need some way to 'mark' certain functions, blocks of code or scopes as being part of that 'phase'. A certain chunk of code can be part of multiple phases, so that when there are chunks B and C that depend on chunk A, I could mark A as being part of 'phase1' and 'phase2' and then when I run phase1, it would run chunk A and chunkB, and for phase2, chunk A and chunk C. I hope this still makes sense.

So I was thinking that decorators would be perfect to do this, so that I could do (conceptually) something like

```
@partOfAPhase("phase1", "phase2")
def f1():
    pass
```

and then somehow, I pass a list of 'phases' to run to my program (either from the command line, or by setting it as a configuration variable somewhere) and when my program is run, it only executes the functions that were decorated as being part of one of the phases specified to be run.

*So*, what I think I need is a generic decorator that can be applied to either functions or member functions which accept any number of arguments, and I need to be able to pass a list of 'tags' to the decorator itself. Then inside the decorator, I need to check (when the original function or member is called) whether the tags of that decorator exist in a global (maybe class static?) list of tags to run.

I looked at https://gist.github.com/Zearin/2f40b7b9cfc51132851a and it seems, at the very end, to do more or less what I want, yet I can't quite puzzle all pieces together to do what I want. More specifically I don't really understand the double nested decorator generator and whether I would need two functions or just one to implement this, and also how I'd get access to the argument that are passed to the decorator (i.e. the phases to run).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this covers your needs but here is a quick and dirty proof of concept:

```
# This first part could go in its own module or a class or whatever
_program = []

def partOfPhase(*phases):
    def decorator(fn):
        _program.append((fn, tuple(phases)))
        return fn
    return decorator

def partOfProgram(fn):
    _program.append((fn, None))
    return fn

def runProgram(phase):
    for fn, fn_phases in _program:
        if fn_phases is None or any(p in fn_phases for p in phases):
            fn()

# This is the actual script
import sys

@partOfPhase('phase1')
def step1():
    print('step1')

@partOfPhase('phase1', 'phase2')
def step2():
    print('step2')

@partOfProgram
def step3():
    print('step3')

@partOfPhase('phase2')
def step4():
    print('step4')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phases = sys.argv[1:]
    runProgram(phases)
```

If you save it as `phases.py`, for example, you would get:

```
> python phases.py
step3

> python phases.py phase1
step1
step2
step3

> python phases.py phase2
step3
step4

> python phases.py phase1 phase2
step1
step2
step3
step4
```

---

*EDIT*

I think this is probably more like what you were thinking, functions that become disabled depending on the phase:

```
# This first part could go in its own module or a class or whatever
from functools import wraps

_enabledPhases = []

def enablePhase(*phases):
    _enabledPhases.extend(phases)

def partOfPhase(*phases):
    def decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)  # Just "cosmetic" wrapping
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            if any(p in phases for p in _enabledPhases):
                fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return decorator

# This is the actual script
import sys

@partOfPhase('phase1')
def step1():
    print('step1')

@partOfPhase('phase1', 'phase2')
def step2():
    print('step2')

def step3():
    print('step3')

@partOfPhase('phase2')
def step4():
    print('step4')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    phases = sys.argv[1:]
    enablePhase(*phases)
    step1()
    step2()
    step3()
    step4()
```

Comment: OK thanks - it took be a bit to get my head around this, because it's a different approach than what I've been trying. If I get it correctly, this would run only functions that were decorated, right? Is there a way to make undecorated functions run always? So that the decoration stuff would become optional?

Comment: @Roal Yes, that's right. I updated the answer with a bit of a hacky extension for "always run" blocks. You could always do things more flexible and sophisticated, of course. However, I'm not sure if this would work for you if you had a different kind of approach in mind that you prefer or need.

Comment: @Roel Okay I have added a slightly different approach which I _think_ may be more like what you were initially thinking of...

Comment: Thank you, your last iteration is mostly what I was looking for, but I saw it too late and got a slightly different way working in the mean time (see my comment) :) Thanks anyway, one question still: in def enablePhase(*phases):, what does the asterisk before 'phases' mean?

Comment: @Roel Ah that means that the list `phases` is "unpacked" so each element is a different argument. For example, if you have a function `f(arg1, arg2)` and call it like `f(*['a', 'b'])` then `arg1` would be `'a'` and `arg2` would be `'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with, after finding out that the method as it is presented in the link is very convoluted and it's much easier to do this with a callable decorator object. This works on both free standing functions and methods, that take any number of arguments (with some simple tests that just print easily visually verified results):

```
import functools
import sys

class runConditional(object):
    def __init__(self, datasets):
        self.datasets = datasets

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            global to_run
            for d in self.datasets:
                if d in to_run:
                    sys.stdout.write(" 1")
                    func(*args, **kwargs)
                    return
            sys.stdout.write(" 0")

        return wrapped_f

@runConditional([1])
def fun1():
    pass

@runConditional([2])
def fun2():
    pass

@runConditional([1,2,3])
def fun3(arg1, arg2):
    pass

def fun_always():
    sys.stdout.write(" 1")
    pass

@runConditional([])
def fun_never():
    pass

class test():
    @runConditional([1])
    def m1(self):
        pass

    @runConditional([2])
    def m2(self):
        pass

    @runConditional([1,2,3])
    def m3(self, arg1):
        pass

    def m_always(self):
        sys.stdout.write(" 1")
        pass

    @runConditional([])
    def m_never(self):
        pass

def run_test(funcs_to_run, expected):
    global to_run
    t = test()
    funcs = [ fun1, fun2, functools.partial(fun3, "123", "meh"), fun_always, fun_never,
            t.m1, t.m2, functools.partial(t.m3, "321"), t.m_always, t.m_never ]
    to_run = funcs_to_run
    print "Expected: " + " ".join(map(str, expected))
    sys.stdout.write("Actual:  ")
    for f in funcs:
        f()
    print ""
    print ""

run_test([2],       [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ])
run_test([1],       [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ])
run_test([],        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ])
run_test([1, 2],    [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ])
```